# Proper usage for term, addend, factor, multiplicand, expression, formula

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, definition, education

The definitions and usage of the following words seem to vary, depending on the source text:

- term
- addend
- factor
- multiplicand
- expression
- formula

The words are being used in the context of pre-algebra and algebra education. Where could I find authoritative definitions and/or usage guides for the above words?

Comment: There is almost never a single meaning for words. Maybe addend has a single meaning, but the rest do not.

Comment: For example, in $a\times b = c$, some people call both $a$ and $b$ a multiplicand, but others only call $a$ that, and call $b$ the multiplier. That is likely because multiplication in a lot of contexts is non-commutative. All the rest are heavily context-dependent.